# How to Resize imageview size using ontouch Android

Tags: android, imageview

I have an ImageView which I want to "resize", not re-sizing the Image but the ImageView, I know I have to implement it using onTouch, but I what I do not know is how to use the given Coordinates in getting a resize, a good example would be WhatsApp, when one ought to set a new display Image on android, it takes them to the gallery then it brings up a "grid" like view which has 8 points, one of each corner and one in between the two points at each corner, you can resize that view how you like it, you can drag the points and the view sizes updates to drop point height and width, how Can i implement such a view? all help will be highly appreciated

Comment: What is the problem? Do you need your image resized when you click on it? How do you see it now?

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

look at this [Moving Images on the Screen with Android](http://obviam.net/index.php/moving-images-on-the-screen-with-androi/)

[How to use Multi-touch in Android 2: Part 6, Implementing the Pinch Zoom Gesture](http://www.zdnet.com/article/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-6-implementing-the-pinch-zoom-gesture/)

Comment: I have all that set up, I dont know maybe I haven't explained it well, but I want to be able to resize the "ImageView" and not the "Image" in the imageview, I want to do this using onTouch